# CORS policy error only in file uploading API in DotNet 7

Tags: .net-core, cors

I'm receiving the following error only in `UploadDocument` API in DotNet 7:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://one.example.com:81/api/Common/UploadDocument' from origin 'http://two.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

All APIs are working fine on local and server machine, But the `UploadDocument` API is only working locally, but not on the server machine. I'm using Windows Server.

This is my controller-level code:

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [Route("UploadDocument")]

    public object UploadDocument()
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = null;
            foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
            {
                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Documents");
                fileName = file.FileName;

                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathToSave))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);

                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Ok(new { Name = fileName });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            _logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I already configured CORS in DotNet 7 program.cs that's why other APIs are working fine except `UploadDocument` API.